# Value of type 'SKSpriteNode' has no member 'setscale'

Tags: swift, skspritenode

I'm following this YouTube series where you learn to program games when there popped up an error, so I fixed that error but that led to another error. And I'm pretty sure I've done exactly as the YouTuber has.

so if you know the solution please help me. (:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


    var bird = SKSpriteNode()
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -5.0);

        var BirdTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Flappy_Bird")
        BirdTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

        bird = SKSpriteNode(texture: BirdTexture)
        bird.setscale(0.5)
        bird.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.35, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.6)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
         /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's just a typo: The method is called `setScale()`